# How to merge two tables that have same table structure? in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In the following script, the outputs are displayed as two separate tables (each with two columns). How can I display both tables in a table with three columns?

```
# Create a hash table for File QTY
$Qty = @{}

# Create a hash table for file size
$Size = @{}

# Import all files into one $Files
$Files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\' -Filter *.* -Recurse -File

# Create a loop to check $file in $Files
foreach ($file in $Files) {
    # Count files based on Extension 
    $Qty[$file.Extension] += 1
    # Summarize file sizes based on their format
    $Size[$file.Extension] += $file.Length / 1GB
}

# Show File QTY table
$Qty 
# Show file size table
$Size
```

Like this:

```
Type    Size    Qyt
-----   -----   -----   
.jpg    10 GB   10000
.png    30 GB   30000
.tif    40 GB   40000
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the keys (the file extensions) from one table and use that as a "driver" to construct a new set of objects with the size and quantity values from the tables:

```
$Qty.psbase.Keys |Select-Object @{Name='Type';Expression={$_}},@{Name='Size';Expression={$Size[$_]}},@{Name='Qty'; Expression={$Qty[$_]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you already got an answer that does exactly what you asked for, I would take a different approach, that doesn't need hashtables:

```sh
# Import all files into one $Files
$Files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\' -Filter *.* -Recurse -File

# Group files by extension and collect the per-extension information
$Files | Group-Object -Property Extension |
    Select-Object @{ n = 'Type'; e = 'Name' },
                  @{ n = 'Size'; e = { '{0:0.00} GB' -f (($_.Group | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB) } },
                  @{ n = 'Qty';  e = 'Count' }
```

Output is like:

```text
Type    Size       Qty
-----   -----      -----   
.jpg    10.23 GB   10000
.png    30.07 GB   30000
.tif    40.52 GB   40000
```

- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2) produces an object per unique file extension. It has a property `Count`, which is the number of grouped items, so we can use that directly. Its property `Name` contains the file extension. Its `Group` property contains all `FileInfo` objects from `Get-ChildItem` that have the same extension.
- Using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) we rename the `Name` property to `Type` and rename the `Count` property to `Qty`. We still need to calculate the total size per file type, which is done using `Measure-Object -Sum`. Using the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f) `-f` we pretty-print the result.
- Replace `{0:0.00}` by `{0:0}` to remove the fractional digits from the `Size` column.
- The syntax `@{ n = ...; e = ... }` is shortcut for `@{ name = ...; expression = ... }` to create a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2).
- You may defer the formatting of the `Size` column to `Format-Table`, to be able to do additional processing based on the numeric value, e. g. sorting:

  ```sh
  $files | Group-Object -Property Extension |
      Select-Object @{ n = 'Type'; e = 'Name' },
                    @{ n = 'Size'; e = { ($_.Group | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum } },
                    @{ n = 'Qty';  e = 'Count' } |
      Sort-Object Size -Descending |
      Format-Table 'Type', @{ n = 'Size'; e = { '{0:0} GB' -f ($_.Size / 1GB) } }, 'Qty'
  ```